# Firebase database rules date extension

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my current firebase real-time database rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1633017600000",  // 2021-10-1
    ".write": "now < 1633017600000",  // 2021-10-1
  }
}
```

I understand that these rules are not secure but is there any way I can extend these rules beyond 2021-10-1 by changing the numbers? Can't find anything regarding '1633017600000' in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just Timestamp since UNIX Epoch in milliseconds. If you want to update to extend that time you can get a timestamp at [Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/) and enter your desired duration to get the timstamp. If you just don't want the time at first place then set the rules to true:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true"
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Again, setting these to true allows anyone to read/write to database so I'd recommend implementing the security rules as per your use case.

Comment: Thank you yes i understand that they are insecure just a placeholder for now. I have accepted this as the answer